# "SystemClock.uptimeMillis() method in android"

Tags: android, linux

Android documentation says "**uptimeMillis() is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted**" for **SystemClock.uptimeMillis()** method. What is the meaning of "**since the system was booted**" ? Is it the time since power button was pressed or the time since start of kernel?

Answer (score 1):

When I do it with my devices, it seems to start counting a couple of seconds after the `power button` is pressed, so I would say it **starts counting** as soon as the `kernel` starts